# What should go inside a functional component

Tags: reactjs

While writing a functional component in React, where do you keep the constants and utility functions? Inside the react component or outside?

```js
import React from 'react';

// A global constant
const EARTH_RADIUS = 3959;

// A utility function
const volume = () => {
  return (4/3) * (22/7) * Math.pow(EARTH_RADIUS, 3);
}

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Earth's radius: {EARTH_RADIUS}</h1>
      <p>{volume()}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Should `EARTH_RADIUS` and `volume` be inside `MyComponent`? Is there any rule when to include or exclude, what's the best practice for this?

Comment: Everything inside a functional component will get destroyed and re-created each render. Typically this doesn't make a observable performance difference, but its something to keep in mind. Its going to come down to preference and how makes since logically to group things. I usually keep things declared inside the function for organization purposes.

Comment: Thanks, this answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do it is creating a folder called **config** or **utils** to put this kind of code in order to reused it in others components.

I hope this help you